# Having trouble using M PLUS Rounded 1c in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm able to get Quicksand working on my react-native but not M PLUS Rounded 1c font for my font family. Is this font just not usable in reac tnative? I'm using regular react native proejct and ran:

```
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
  },
  assets: ['./assets/fonts'],
};
```

and

`npx react-native-asset`

after storing all the fonts inside the assets folder